# Saving a snapshot of all objects, variables and everything in R

Tags: r, environment, restore

Is using there an good alternative for using the following command:

```
save.image("MyEnvSnaphot.Rdata")
```

For saving every variable with its value, objects (lists, arrays, dataframes etc.) and restore it for the same point as before by `load`? Does it work for bigdata matrices and dataframes?

Comment: `save.image` works fine here, any particular reason for alternative?

Comment: I tried to restore the data after crash and some of the variables were lost. Is it due to bigdata?

Comment: Yes, primarily due to your machine's RAM availability.

Comment: Is it the only option? Is there a better alternative for image snapshot saving for bigdata?

Comment: I am not very sure about alternative, but you could explore if `docker` would be helpful!